# Set environment variables in Xcode from Jenkins shell script

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

Is there a way to change the environment variables for Xcode 6 (running on OS X Yosemite) build settings from Jenkins shell script? e.g. How do I do the following directly from the script : "CODE_SIGN_RESOURCE_RULES_PATH=$(SDKROOT)/ResourceRules.plist" ?